# Retrieving a parameter in an object within an ArrayList in C#?

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class People{

    public string name;
    public int type;

}

public class Game{
    public ArrayList people;

    public void start(){
        People p = new People();
        p.name = "Vitor";
        p.type = 1;

        people = new ArrayList ();
        people.add(p);

        Debug.Log(p[0].name);
    }
}
```

Returned error:

> Type 'object' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no
>   extension method 'name' of type 'object' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: if `people` will only contain objects of type `People`, then it is much better to declare it as `List<People>` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: What Ahmad said is correct, `ArrayList` is a very old class, and in almost every case you should use a `List<TypeOfTheContents>`. In fact, most people use `List<object>` instead of `ArrayList`, when needed.

Answer (score 6):

The [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) is comprised of objects, so you need to cast it:

```
Debug.Log(((People)people[0]).name);
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `Debug.Log((people[0] as People).name);`.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use Linq:

```
Debug.Log(people.OfType<Person>().First().name);
```

Anyway, if it is possible you should generic collection, f.e. `List<Perople>`.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `ArrayList` are always of type `object`. You need to cast them back to the type you want. But be wary that it's still possible to put another type of object inside the `ArrayList`, and if you try casting that to `People`, it will throw an error.

Anyways, here's how to cast:

```
People first = (People) people[0];
Debug.Log(first.name);
```

Or all in one line (note the parentheses):

```
Debug.Log(((People) people[0]).name);
```

---

With that said, you should definitely use the type [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `ArrayList`. Reason is, it protects your code from errors by only accepting the specified type `T` as contents, and when you access an item, it is already of type `T`. Your code, rewritten with `List<People>`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class People {
    public string name;
    public int type;
}

public class Game {
    public List<People> people;

    public void Start() {
        People p = new People();
        p.name = "Vitor";
        p.type = 1;

        people = new List<People>();
        people.Add(p);

        Debug.Log(p[0].name);
    }
}
```

Note that now you do not need to cast the contents, when accessing with `p[0]`.